# How to deselect all items in a combobox?

Tags: vbscript, combobox, hp-uft, uft14

I have a drop down combobox that I need to deselect all of the options in there.

I've tried selecting every item using the select option and making it equal to false, it's not working, I also tried doing the same with getItem.

```
For It = 1 To wpfwindow("window").WpfComboBox("randComboBox").GetItemsCount -1
     wpfwindow("window").WpfComboBox("randComboBox").select(It) = false
```

I want everything to be deselected

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `WpfComboBox` supports having no element selected. From a look at the [documentation of `WpfComboBox.Select`](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.51/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#NET_WPF/WpfPackageLib~WpfComboBox.html#Select) I see two problems with your code.

1. (major) `Select` selects an item, it doesn't return a boolean saying whether it's selected, so settign it to false won't do anything.
2. (minor) It says that **The first item in a list is numbered 0** so starting `It` with `1` is an error (if you start with one you should end with `GetItemsCount` not with `GetItemsCount-1`).

Comment: I figured that `Select` doesn't return a boolean, it was just something that I tried, and I didn't want to access the first element.

Comment: And if it dosen't support it, is there any way that I could make sure that's everything is not selected?

Comment: I've seen that they are being mentioned (when recording) as `checkboxes` but I can't access them any other way, and even after I'm done recording and debugging it just says that he can't find them

Comment: Sorry @IdoHLevi I'm not very fluent with WPF, in Web there is `Deselect` but I don't know about WPF,  I just went according to the documentation.